# how to avoid calling location did update for three times

Tags: iphone, dictionary

**location did update** calling three time and **location did fail with error** not call even when no data receive
how to avoid calling **location did update** three times and call **did fail with error** for no data receive?

---

> im not taking about internet connection

Comment: Why would location updates require internet? If it's an actual iPhone, it has a GPC chip which works with or without internet equally well (give or take the 20 minutes it might take to update the almanac). What problem are you *actually* trying to solve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How to avoid calling three times location did update?**

for ios location update delegate may call several time depend upon on speed not three times 
so use bool variable to indicate

> **How to call did fail with error for no internet connection?**

you have set location manger delegate with self

Comment: location set delegate self

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid calling three times location did update?

Set location manager's delegate to nil in this method.

> How to call did fail with error for no internet connection?

Why should it be called? Locations may come from three sources: GPS radio, cellular and WiFi, but not from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager didUpdateToLocation always check for change in location. If it fing multiple location it will call multiple time. You can avoid it in different way. But this will not update the location if user changes his current place.

You can user this code just to get location and proceed further.

-(void)getLocation{

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
```

// [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];   commented to avoid multiple calling or you can say updating current location
    CLLocation *newLocation=[locationManager location];
    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

```
    NSString * location = ([placemarks count] > 0) ? [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] locality] : @"Not Found";
    NSLog(@"location:%@",location);
    NSLog(@"lat:%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"long:%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
}];
```

}